# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' dynamic controls

Tags: vb.net

In my program I have several radiobuttons which load dynamic fields. When I select the first radiobutton, all the fields are loaded. But when I select another radiobutton, the fields don't appear and I got the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I tried to clear the Placeholder, but it didn't worked. I think the problem is related with the radiobuttons because when I comment it out, everything works perfectly. But sadly I need these buttons.

I know that this question has been asked many times, and I also tried to solve my problem with the different topics, but I don't know what to do now...

*Here is the code*

```
 Protected Sub ServiceTypeList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ServiceTypeList.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim tmpservicetype As New servicetype(ServiceTypeList.SelectedItem.Value)
        Dim tmpFieldName As String

    Try
        Dim cmdstr As String
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear()
        lblText.Controls.Clear()

        cmdstr = "SELECT servicetype, FieldName, FieldType, FieldLength, FieldLabelEmail, ToolboxType, Height, Width, TabIndex FROM tblDynamicControl WHERE (servicetype = '" & tmpservicetype.servicetype & "') ORDER BY TabIndex"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdstr)

        Dim dt As DataTable = EMGEHelpdesk.SharedCode.ExecuteCMD(cmd).Tables(0)
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(i)
            tmpFieldName = SetDataVar(dr, "FieldName")
            Dim NewField As New DynamicControl(tmpservicetype.servicetype, tmpFieldName, "GB")

            Select Case NewField.ToolboxType
                Case "TextBox"
                    Dim DXTextbox As ASPxTextBox
                    Dim DXLabel As ASPxLabel
                    DXTextbox = New ASPxTextBox
                    DXTextbox.ID = NewField.FieldName & "_field"
                    DXTextbox.Width = NewField.Width
                    DXTextbox.Height = NewField.Height
                    DXTextbox.TabIndex = NewField.TabIndex
                    DXTextbox.CssClass = "Field"
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DXTextbox)        --> **The error appears here**
                    DXLabel = New ASPxLabel
                    DXLabel.ID = NewField.FieldName.ToString & "_lbl"
                    DXLabel.Text = NewField.lblText
                    DXLabel.CssClass = "TextBox"
                    lblText.Controls.Add(DXLabel)
                    DXTextbox.Controls.Add(DXLabel)

                Case "RadioButton"
                    Dim BXRadiobutton As ASPxRadioButtonList
                    Dim BXLabel As ASPxLabel
                    BXRadiobutton = New ASPxRadioButtonList
                    BXRadiobutton.DataSource = Split(NewField.FieldName)
                    BXRadiobutton.DataBind()
                    BXRadiobutton.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
                    BXRadiobutton.ID = NewField.FieldName & "_field"
                    BXRadiobutton.TabIndex = NewField.TabIndex
                    BXRadiobutton.CssClass = "Button"
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(BXRadiobutton)
                    BXLabel = New ASPxLabel
                    BXLabel.ID = NewField.FieldName.ToString & "_lbl"
                    BXLabel.Text = NewField.lblText
                    BXLabel.CssClass = "RadioButton"
                    lblText.Controls.Add(BXLabel)
                    BXRadiobutton.Controls.Add(BXLabel)

                Case "MemoBox"
                    Dim MXMemobox As ASPxMemo
                    Dim MXLabel As ASPxLabel
                    MXMemobox = New ASPxMemo
                    MXMemobox.ID = NewField.FieldName & "_field"
                    MXMemobox.Width = NewField.Width
                    MXMemobox.Height = NewField.Height
                    MXMemobox.TabIndex = NewField.TabIndex
                    MXMemobox.CssClass = "Field"
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MXMemobox)
                    MXLabel = New ASPxLabel
                    MXLabel.ID = NewField.FieldName.ToString & "_lbl"
                    MXLabel.Text = NewField.lblText
                    MXLabel.CssClass = "MemoBox"
                    lblText.Controls.Add(MXLabel)
                    MXMemobox.Controls.Add(MXLabel)
            End Select

        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And on that line, what is `Nothing` - `PlaceHolder1`, `PlaceHolder1.Controls` or `DXTextbox`?

Comment: PlaceHolder1 is the PlaceHolders name, Placeholder1.Controls.Add allows me to add a control on the placeholder and DXTextbox is the name of the textbox. Basically, this line allows me to add the textboxes (add a new control for each textbox). And where do you see "Nothing" ?

Comment: May you show us the model of PlaceHolder1? The error occur when you try to add object to it, but you cannot add a object to **Nothing**.

Comment: @PSo what do you mean with "I cannot add an object to **Nothing**" ? And for your information, the PlaceHolder1 is a simple PlaceHolder with nothing inside.

Comment: @georges619 You created a new instance of DXTextbox = New ASPxTextBox, that's why the problem should not belongs to DXTextbox, should belong to PlaceHolder1. Where did you declare this variable? Or look at a outer scope of this problem, what would this piece of code do when you click another button or input option?

Comment: @PSo The problem cannot be the PlaceHolder1 because if it was, I could not generate any field and that's not what happens. You said "what would this piece of code do when you click another button or input option?" Look. I have 15 radiobuttons in a menu. When I click one of these button, the fields are generated dynamically. But when I select another, the error appears while loading the first field.

Comment: Please do the basic debugging @georges619. When execution stops at the line with the error, hover the cursor over each of `PlaceHolder1`, `PlaceHolder1.Controls` and `DXTextbox` on that line to learn which one is [`Nothing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx).

Comment: @GSerg I did what you told me. When I hover the cursor over `PlaceHolder1` this appears (PlaceHolder1|{System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder}) ; when I hover it over `PlaceHolder1.Controls` this appears (PlaceHolder1.Controls|{System.Web.UI.ControlCollection}) ; when I hover the cursor over `DXTextbox` this appears (DXTextbox|{System.Web.ASPxTextBox})
There is no element which is nothing... This is weird :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I declared the new instance outside, and tried to reuse the variable as you mentioned. It worked at the first time.

```
Protected Sub ServiceTypeList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ServiceTypeList.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim tmpservicetype As New servicetype(ServiceTypeList.SelectedItem.Value)
    Dim tmpFieldName As String

Try
    Dim cmdstr As String
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear()
    lblText.Controls.Clear()

    cmdstr = "SELECT servicetype, FieldName, FieldType, FieldLength, FieldLabelEmail, ToolboxType, Height, Width, TabIndex FROM tblDynamicControl WHERE (servicetype = '" & tmpservicetype.servicetype & "') ORDER BY TabIndex"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdstr)

    Dim dt As DataTable = EMGEHelpdesk.SharedCode.ExecuteCMD(cmd).Tables(0)
    Dim DXTextbox As ASPxTextBox
    Dim DXLabel As ASPxLabel
    DXTextbox = New ASPxTextBox
    DXLabel = New ASPxLabel
    Dim BXRadiobutton As ASPxRadioButtonList
    Dim BXLabel As ASPxLabel
    BXRadiobutton = New ASPxRadioButtonList
    BXLabel = New ASPxLabel
    Dim MXMemobox As ASPxMemo
    Dim MXLabel As ASPxLabel
    MXMemobox = New ASPxMemo
    MXLabel = New ASPxLabel

    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(i)
        tmpFieldName = SetDataVar(dr, "FieldName")
        Dim NewField As New DynamicControl(tmpservicetype.servicetype, tmpFieldName, "GB")

        Select Case NewField.ToolboxType
            Case "TextBox"                    
                DXTextbox.ID = NewField.FieldName & "_field"
                DXTextbox.Width = NewField.Width
                DXTextbox.Height = NewField.Height
                DXTextbox.TabIndex = NewField.TabIndex
                DXTextbox.CssClass = "Field"
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DXTextbox)
                DXLabel.ID = NewField.FieldName.ToString & "_lbl"
                DXLabel.Text = NewField.lblText
                DXLabel.CssClass = "TextBox"
                lblText.Controls.Add(DXLabel)
                DXTextbox.Controls.Add(DXLabel)

            Case "RadioButton"                    
                BXRadiobutton.DataSource = Split(NewField.FieldName)
                BXRadiobutton.DataBind()
                BXRadiobutton.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
                BXRadiobutton.ID = NewField.FieldName & "_field"
                BXRadiobutton.TabIndex = NewField.TabIndex
                BXRadiobutton.CssClass = "Button"
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(BXRadiobutton)                    
                BXLabel.ID = NewField.FieldName.ToString & "_lbl"
                BXLabel.Text = NewField.lblText
                BXLabel.CssClass = "RadioButton"
                lblText.Controls.Add(BXLabel)
                BXRadiobutton.Controls.Add(BXLabel)

            Case "MemoBox"                   
                MXMemobox.ID = NewField.FieldName & "_field"
                MXMemobox.Width = NewField.Width
                MXMemobox.Height = NewField.Height
                MXMemobox.TabIndex = NewField.TabIndex
                MXMemobox.CssClass = "Field"
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MXMemobox)
                MXLabel.ID = NewField.FieldName.ToString & "_lbl"
                MXLabel.Text = NewField.lblText
                MXLabel.CssClass = "MemoBox"
                lblText.Controls.Add(MXLabel)
                MXMemobox.Controls.Add(MXLabel)
        End Select

    Next


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: It don't work :/. It's doing almost the same thing (when I click the first radiobutton) but there are a few fields missing. And when I select another button, the error appears again...

Comment: Up to now, to be honest i have no clue where your problem is, the error msg told us, in your line **PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DXTextbox)**, there is one thing has not been initialized,which is **nothing**